# Curl, post current time

Tags: macos, unix, post, curl

I fire this command using a cronjob (I'm on a Mac) every hour:

```
/usr/bin/curl -s --data "gr=0123&press=OK" http://www.myurl.com/myphp.php >/dev/null
```

Is there any way to post my current time in HH:MM format, adding a new post parameter? How?

Answer (score 1):

First off, in case you haven't figured it out already, to get just the time in the Macintosh shell, you can do:

```
date +"%H:%M"
```

So, to answer your question, how about trying:

```
/usr/bin/curl -s --data "gr=0123&press=OK&time=`date +'\%H:\%M'`" http://www.myurl.com/myphp.php >/dev/null
```

and if that doesn't work, try doing this (all on one line)

```
setenv CURRENTTIME `date +'\%H:\%M'` ; /usr/bin/curl -s --data "gr=0123&press=OK&time=$CURRENTTIME" http://www.myurl.com/myphp.php >/dev/null
```

Note that you need to escape the percent symbols; otherwise, cron will convert them to newlines and pass every line but the first via stdin to the command. From the [crontab(5)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/crontab.5.html) manpage:

> The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the cronfile.  Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.

Considering that the command line is starting to grow rather long, it might be better to place it in a shell script, and call the script as the cron job.

Comment: I copied and pasted your solution but it silently fails.

Comment: silently fails? hmmm... I used to have a cgi-bin applet on a site of mine where I could see parameters I sent to the HTTP address. I wasn't able to test my code out, but I'm pretty certain my solution is close.

Comment: @AsTheWormTurns : maybe it is the `> dev/null` at the end of cmd ?

Comment: Is it possibile to put date +"%H:%M" in a variable before the concatenation?

Comment: it may be... but it looks like that one line is your only entry into your crontab?

Comment: Yes, it is the only line. I was supposing something wrong with quotes. If I omit that part anything works.

Comment: I've modified my answer (last line) to offer another option. I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: thank you. It doesn't work. Don't worry, I'll find another solution.   :-)

Comment: This is where the shell script might help. One issue with the command is explained on the [crontab](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/crontab.5.html) man page: percents are replaced with newlines.