# PHP, adjust time retrieved

Tags: php, time, format

I have a cronjob that calls a PHP file via CURL every hour from one of my computers. When the file is called, the PHP code retrieves the server time, since it should record it in a database field in HH:MM format.

Client and server are not perfectly synced, so, when the client calls the PHP file, it can happen that for the client it's 14 o'clock, while for the server it's still 13:59. 13:59 is not acceptable for my db, since I should have always 14:00, 15:00, 16:00 and so on.

I can't send parameters via CURL because of an [unsolved issue with time and my computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309599/curl-post-current-time) AND I can't change the server time.

The only thing I could try is to adjust the time retrieved from PHP, and, when it's 13:59 (or even 14:01), adjust and save it as 14:00. Is there any PHP *magics* to solve this problem? My idea is to convert the time to 13,59 (or 14,01), then round them in some way, but maybe there are better options.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you really want the server time. Why not use the local time?

Comment: As I said, I can't send the client time using a CURL POST parameter.

Comment: Are you talking about recording the time on the server, or the client? Note you don't need to post data, you can also pass data via the query string. This is easier if you create a shell script for the request and use the script for the cron job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to get the nearest hour in an `HH:MM` format string that I can think of is:

**FIXED** (again)

```
$nearest_hour = str_pad(round(date('H') + ((date('i') - 1) / 60)),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':00';
```

Comment: So, your idea is to get 13.9 or 14.1, then round them. If so, it is exactly the compact code I was looking for.

Comment: That's the idea - convert hours:minutes to a decimal float, then round it to the nearest integer.

Comment: @AsTheWormTurns I have just realised that the original code is slightly flawed, because it does not account for seconds and will give `9:00` when the time is `9:30:59`, when it should be `10:00`. For your purposes this probably does not matter, since the time on your server/client is unlikely to be that for out, but for completeness I have updated with a fix.

Comment: It doesn't matter for my purposes, but thanks for the quick fix.

Comment: I must correct your script because now it writes 8:00 instead of 08:00 (8:00 is not HH:MM). Would this be ok or there's a more elegant/efficient/compact way? `$rounded_hour = round(date('H') + ((date('i') - 1) / 60)); $nearest_hour = $rounded_hour<10 ? "0".$rounded_hour.":00" : $rounded_hour.":00".` I must try this one too: `$nearest_hour = sprintf("%02d",round(date('H') + ((date('i') - 1) / 60))).":00";`

Comment: @AsTheWormTurns I would `str_pad()` it as edited above, but whatever works for you really.

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = '13:59';
list($h, $m) = explode(':', $time);
$h += $m > 30;

echo $h . ':00';
```

how about such dummy solution? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Say you have your time string in `$time` formatted as `HH:MM` and the timestamp in `$timestamp`. You do:

```
$t_str = explode(':', $time);
$hour = (int)t_str[0];
$min = (int)t_str[1];
if($min >= 30)
 $hour++;

if($hour == 24)
 $hour = 0;

$time = "{$hour}:00";
```

And your time will be set appropriately.

Comment: @zerkms Yeah I just noticed my error and corrected it. Thanks.